# Gh pages on deploy not rendering src or public folder w/ React

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

When I deployed my app I did everything correctly and it deployed to github. However, the src and folder public did not deploy on npm run deploy. The only files that were deployed were the static files. I've looked at other deployments and they didn't have the static folder, just the public and src. I've tried to do research on this issue but nothing seems to pertain to my particular problem. I don't know what I am doing wrong. The pages show up on github but I would also like to have the code with it as well. I am running it from the terminal instead of git bash if that helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: same here. have you solved it?: